# React not displaying correct route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am putting together a small application to get used to React, now I have installed React-Router-Dom and when I click a link the URL correctly changes. The issue is that the correct Component does not display.

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Sidebar from './Components/Sidebar';
import SidebarItem from './Components/SidebarItem';
import Home from './Components/Home';

import './App.scss';
import { Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Link to='/home'>Home</Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/home' Component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Can anyone tell me the reason why HomeComponent does not appear?

Comment: Top tip: Your constructor is pointless. Remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prop of the `Route` that takes a component is spelled `component` with a small `c`, not `Component`.

**Example**

```
function Home() {
  return <div> Home </div>;
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```